# In Postman Test script Can we execute another request in collection

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

In collection I have 5 requests. In one of a request I want to script in Test tab that after getting a response to execute a request already in the collection.

I cant find references/blogs/article for accessing requests in collection. Alternatively I can write a request. But I need to set authorization logic, and other settings.

Comment: For more flexibility, you could use `pm.sendRequest()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below script in the request from where you want to trigger the next request.
Note that request names has to be unique in a collection.
[Refer this link for more details](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/building-workflows/)

> postman.setNextRequest("Request Name")

**Update**
If you want to send a request after a single request is run, use

> pm.sendRequest()

[Refer this for pm.sendRequest](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmsendrequest)

Note that pm.sendRequest has to include all parameters such as request URL, authentication etc., and is NOT a postman request self that is visible under a collection.

Comment: Will it work if I just execute the single request instead of running collection ?

Comment: Nope, `postman.setNextRequest()` works only in collection runner.